# Click dataset converts everything to 1

Tags: ms-access

I am currently busy with my thesis data and am using MS Access to create a data base. I do not have any knowledge about SQL unfortunately.

A sample dataset is available in the link below. In `sheet1` you see the `choice set` of the consumer. In `sheet2` of the file, you see the `click data` of the users that visited the website and saw the `choice set`. The goal is to link these two sheets together, so that the `Shopnames` in `sheet2` will get a `1` and all the other `Shopnames` will get a `0`.

The problem is: Access gives them all an `1` in `Query1`, where I expected an `0` for the shops that were not present in `sheet2`. I do not understand why this happens. Could anyone help me?

[image: Sheet 1]
[image: Sheet 2]
[image: Query1]

SQL code:

`SELECT Sheet2.[Session IDs], Sheet2.[Visit Time], Sheet2.[Device Class], [Sheet1]![Click]+[Sheet2]![Click] AS Click, Sheet3.Positie, Sheet1.Productname, Sheet1.Shopname, Sheet1.Ad, Sheet1.Score, Sheet1.[Delivery time], Sheet1.[Basic price], Sheet1.[Delivery costs], Sheet1.[Total price]
FROM (Sheet2 INNER JOIN Sheet3 ON Sheet2.[Session IDs] = Sheet3.[Session IDs]) INNER JOIN Sheet1 ON Sheet3.Positie = Sheet1.Positie;`

Comment: I don't think anyone is inclined to download a random person's database. Can you include some things like table schema and your SQL?

Comment: am i seeing it correct? your shop names in sheet1 begins with a space? and shop name in sheet2 is trimmed. There is no way you can get any valuable info out of this dataset unless you correct your data first ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're simply adding `[Sheet1]![Click]+[Sheet2]![Click]`.. Every single record has a 1 in `Sheet2`, so given that; every record will have a 1 for `Click` in your Query.

I don't even see a relationship between `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, and you haven't told us what `Sheet3` contains.

If I was looking for `ShopNames` in `Sheet1` that may/may not be in `Sheet2`, I would do a `LEFT JOIN` from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` on `ShopName`, and for `Click` I would do something like :

`IIf(Sheet1.ShopName = Sheet2.ShopName, 1, 0) AS ClickTest`